# Short-stay Visa Waiver Programme

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, eu, netherlands, ireland

I am an Indian citizen residing in the Netherlands with residence permit long-term resident EU. As per the link here: https://www.irishimmigration.ie/preclearance-and-entry-visas-fees/#SSVWP

> Nationals of the countries included in the Irish Short Stay Visa
> Waiver Programme who are long term legal residents in the UK or
> Schengen area

Is this correct and applicable to me and my dependent spouse?

Comment: Is your dependent spouse also Indian or nationals of a covered country?

Comment: Also, note that it is not a visa waiver (the reference visa waiver program, which requires a UK visa and travelling to the UK before Ireland, is simply a convenient way to classify certain countries), but a visa fee waiver. You will still have to apply for a visa but you will not have to pay the fee if you are eligible under this section.

Comment: Yes My spouse also Indian.Thank you